# jquery dataTables search extension, access column information

Tags: jquery, datatables

as from here https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search
I want to write a search plugin but

1. I want it to work based on key I define in `columns:[]`, in my example below `customSearch`
2. Current proposal shows that column needs to be hard coded, in example below `searchData[3] ) || 0; // using the data from the 4th column`

**Objective:**
1. when writing a plugin, How can I target a column for searching if it has certain key defined in `columns:[]` definition

**Sample:**

````
//datatables column definition
columns:[{
    data:"id",
    title:"ID",
    customSearch:"custom"
}]
// writing a search plugin
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {
        var age = parseFloat( searchData[3] ) || 0; // using the data from the 4th column
        // this is hard coded. I dont want that. 
        // 
        // 
        // how can I get  column information here so I can write a plugin based on
        var age = parseFloat(rowData[column.data]) ; // dynamically get data

    }
);
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the `settings` object in the arguments, thus you can filter out columns with certain properties :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {

    var searchColumns = settings.aoColumns.filter(function(c) {
      return c.customSearch && c.customSearch != undefined
    });
    console.log(searchColumns);
```

Now you have an array of columns having a `customSearch` property. You can get the index of a column by its `idx` :

```
var index = searchColumns[0].idx;
```

or the data name property by (surprise) data :

```
var dataProp = searchColumns[0].data;
```

so you could do for example

```
var age = parseFloat(rowData[column[dataProp]])
```